# Is there a comprehensive book treating the theory of characteristic polynomials over modules?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, modules

In most Linear Algebra-courses, the theory of characteristic polynomials of endomorphisms is only treated in the case of $F$-vector spaces $V$, where $F$ is a field. However, in more advanced books, results are used in more general context, where $R$ is a (specific) ring and $M$ is an $R$-module. I am looking for a comprehensive book that covers the theory in a more general context.

So far, I checked the following books: Adkins-Weintraub: *Algebra*; Bosch: *Lineare Algebra*; Bourbaki: *Algebra I-III*; Hoffmann-Kunze: *Linear Algebra*; Lang: *(Linear) Algebra*. However, they treat most results only over fields.

To be more specific:
I was wondering, whether the following the following two propositions hold in a more general setting:

> Let $A: V\to V$ be an endomorphism of a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space $V$. Suppose there is a monic polynomial $p\in F[T]$, such that $V$ is isomorphic to $F[T]/(p)$ as a $F[T]$-module (via A). Then $p$ is both the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

from Bosch's *Lineare Algebra* and

> Let $V=V_1\oplus\ldots\oplus V_r$ be a a direct sum of finite dimensional $F$-vector spaces with an endomorphism $A:V\to V$. Assume $AV_i\subset V_i$ and let $\chi_{A_i}(T)$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$ on $V_i$. Then
>   $$ \chi_A(T)=\prod_i \chi_{A_i}(T),$$
>   thus the characteristic polynomial is multiplicative under direct sums.

from Lang's *Algebra*.